# How to hide duration in the control bar?

Tags: mediaelement.js

i just want to hide the duration in my videos. this is my code on the wordpress page:

```
<video width="720" height="405" poster="/wp-content/uploads/videos/HomeVideo.png" controls="controls" preload="true">
<!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
<source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/videos/HomeVideo.mp4" />
<!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
<source type="video/webm" src="/wp-content/uploads/videos/HomeVideo.webm" />
<!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
<source type="video/ogg" src="/wp-content/uploads/videos/HomeVideo.ogv" />
<!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
<object width="720" height="405" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
    <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=HomeVideo.mp4" />
    <!-- Image as a last resort -->
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/videos/noplay.png" width="720" height="405" />
</object>
```

i delete 'duration' in features in the php but that hadnt any effects. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the solution by myself.
just change the code to:

[video mp4="/wp-content/uploads/videos/HomeVideo.mp4" ogg="/wp-content/uploads/videos/HomeVideo.ogg" webm="/wp-content/uploads/videos/HomeVideo.webm" poster="/wp-content/uploads/videos/HomeVideo.png" preload="true" current="false" width="720" height="405"]

and add to css

.mejs-controls .mejs-time {visibility:hidden !important;display:none !important;}